# How can I import empty in csv file using mysql workbench type double?

Tags: mysql, csv, null, workbench

I have a problem to import csv using mysql workbench.
My table type is double because it is financial data.
When I import using table data import wizard from workbench, I can't import empty cell in csv(excel). There is error 1265 "Data Truancated for column".

I already find this problem, someone said empty cell substitute to \N or Null or "\N" or "Null", but these doesn't works.

How can I import empty cell in csv file to Null using mysql workbench?

Answer (score 0):

That means the criteria for that field has been set to only allow for a certain length of `integer` or `character count` --  For instance `INT(4)` will only allow for an integer that is **4 digits** long.  Or a `float(6,2)` will only allow a 4 digit **whole number** with two **decimals**.

You need to inspect your table, and look at the field being truncated.  One of two things need to happen.

1) You need to expand the allowed size of your field in the database itself.

or

2) You need to curtail the length of the field in the CSV (by means of rounding etc)